# Is it ok to change from full recovery to simple recovery in Sql Server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an old database - a users membership/role that was setup automatically by an ASP.Net 2 application years ago:

[image]

The Sql Server version currently running is: Sql Server 10.5.1617

The users database log file is huge (the ldf file is approx 400 times the size of the mdf file).

The recovery model is currently set to "Full". I understand what that is - and I don't need point in time restoration.

If I simply changed the recovery model to "Simple" from within Sql Server Management Studio:
[image]

...and clicked ok to save the changes - would I be risking my current database in any way?  Or is Sql Server fine with making changes like this to live databases?  And would the log file automatically shrink itself?

Thanks for your advice,

Mark

Comment: Perhaps this question is more suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll do that - thank you Steve, Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer both of your questions:

1. Changing the recovery model on a live database is safe. You shouldn't incur any downtime, blocking, etc.
2. The log file won't shrink itself. You may find that once you've set the recovery model to simple that it may not be shrinkable right away. If you find that you're unable to shrink it, take a look at `dbcc loginfo`, specifically the 'status' column. Each row in the output of that command represents one virtual log file (vlf). The shrink command will only be able to clear a contiguous block of inactive (i.e. status = 0) vlfs at the end of the file. TL;DR - If you've got rows with status = 2 at the bottom, wait until you don't and then shrink.

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine, the transactions have been commited. The log file is waiting to be backed up and therefor released. Changing to Simple Recovery means that you cannot do rolling backups, but data will be commited to the db in the same way as before, logs are simply deleted after sql has completed writing the transaction.